# Is it possible to suspend / stop updating Conky when Desktop is not in focus / is not visible?

Tags: conky

I recently configured Conky, and wanted to know if it is possible to suspend Conky / make it update at a lower rate when the Desktop is not in focus (or not visible)...through some command that can be added to the .conf file or by other means.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, which is why it is important to choose wisely to not run heavy commands using `${exec}` but optimise with `{execi 99}` where 99 says how many seconds to wait before re-running the command.

Use `top` to see how much cpu conky is using before worrying too much.

You can always suspend conky (like any process) with the signal `kill -stop`, and `kill -cont` to continue it, usually with no bad side-effects (except for graphs showing throughput perhaps). You can also `nice` it to make it low priority. But determining whether the whole desktop is obscured is tricky, especially these days with compositing window managers, or Wayland.